# HTML 5 canvas clip very costly

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, clip

I have serious performance problems using canvas clip() with chrome.

[I have made a test case to illustrate](http://jsbin.com/oluJusO/1/edit?js,output).

Even in a simple case like this the red rectangle blinks as if it takes too much time to redraw, and a CPU profiling shows the clip() method takes about 10% of the CPU.

In my real program, it get to 16% and keep increasing each frame until the canvas almost freezes the browser..

Is there something wrong in my use of clip ?

Thank you for any suggestions,

Regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Cause

Insert a `beginPath()` as `rect()` adds to the path unlike `fillRect()`/`strokeRect()`. What happens here is that the rectangles are accumulating eventually slowing the clipping down over time.

This in combination with using `setInterval`, which is not able to synchronize with monitor/screen refreshes, worsens the problem.

To elaborate on the latter:

Using `setInterval()`/`setTimeout()` can cause tearing which happens when the draw is in the "middle" of its operation not fully completed and a screen refresh occur.

`setInterval` can only take integer values and you would need for 16.67 ms to synchronize frame-wise (@60Hz). Even if `setInterval` *could* take floats it would not synchronize the timing with the monitor timing as the timer mechanism isn't bound to monitor at all.

To solve this always use `requestAnimationFrame` to synchronize drawings with screen updates. This is directly linked to monitor refreshes and is a more low-level and efficient implementation than the other, and is made for this purpose, hence the name.

## Solution embedding both fixes above

See **[modified bin here](http://jsbin.com/uvuMatAt/2/edit?js,output)**.

The code for future visitors:

```
function draw() {

  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
  context.save();
  
  context.beginPath();            /// add a beginPath here
  context.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  context.clip();
  
  context.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  
  context.restore();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);    /// use rAF here
}

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.width = width+'px';
canvas.style.height = height+'px';

requestAnimationFrame(draw);      /// start loop
```

PS: If you need to stop the loop inject a condition to run rAF all inside the loop, ie:

```
if (isPlaying) requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

There is BTW no need for `closePath()` as this will be done implicit for you as by [the specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-paths-to-the-canvas). You can add it if you want, but calling `clip()` (or `fill()` etc.) will do this *for* you (specs is addressing browser implementers):

> Open subpaths must be implicitly closed when computing the clipping region

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think about the beginPath(), and your explanation makes perfect sense and explains why it gets slower and slower over time. The requestAnimationFrame arguments were very useful as well, thanks, problem solved! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck with exactly that problem for 2 days now. I did not figure out that clipping was the problem. My app was getting slower and slower with every frame and i did not know what was causing the problem until I stumbled about this.

Comment: I had a similar performance issue when I added `beginPath`, `rect`, `clip` to my draw. I fixed it by inserting `save` and `restore` as in your example.